# Prestashop 1.7 customer custom fields strange behavior

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I added two new variables to the ps_customer database and in customer class:

```
/** @var string ricetta */
public $ricetta;

/** @var int agente */
public $agente;
```

And in the definition array:

```
        'agente' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'size' => 11),
        'ricetta' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true),
```

All is perfect; I can manage these fields in the admin area and in general in the whole environment.

But something very strange happens when on the frontend `PasswordControllerCore` is called.

I discovered that when $customer->update(); consumed, one of two new fields ($ricetta) in database became empty.

The Customer update delete this, but not the other custom field.($agente)

I'm becoming crazy for that ...no way to understand what happening :-(

Comment: I'm sorry Gino, there is just one, sad, word. Debug. dump function can be helpful :).
Oh and don't forget to check how $customer get initialized. Maybe in a strange way

Comment: HI Jack.
I tried to debug.
object is initialized first and after the function customer-update call.
I managed the problem capturing the value first of function call and by manual db update after!
It's a very bad solution but solved...
Now i'm searching for the very cause that seems is related to the ps version.
1.7.6

Comment: that's not good but if it's working, keep it there. Don't forget to put your code in override folder due to prevent updates on core classes